# log file not generated using log4j

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

**Project Structure-**

[image]

**SystemFiler.java**

```
package custom;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class SystemFiler {
    private static final Logger logLogger = LogManager.getLogger(SystemFiler.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {              
            String logMsg = "testcase: "+i;            
            logLogger.info(logMsg);
        }
    }

}
```

**log4j.properties**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=warn

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=some_log_message.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.threshold=INFO
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Comment: And your project structure is?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov- added project structure.

Comment: Where is your log4j2 configuration file? If you read the [Log4j 1.2 Bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/index.html) page it says "The Log4j 1.2 Bridge allows applications coded to use Log4j 1.2 API to use Log4j 2 instead."

Answer (score 0):

Give the full path to appender file name,i.e,


use `log4j.appender.file.File={catalina.home}/some_path/some_log_message.log`